# How can I get second to last segment in URL and skip all GET queries with PHP?

Tags: php, string, url

I have a url - `http://example.com/accounts/users/list?showlist=true&id=4` and I need to get the `users` segment out of this. How can it be done? I know there's `substr` command, but not quite sure how to use it. Can you please show me an example?

Thanks you.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: `parse_url`, `explode`

Comment: Please stop downvoting. `parse_url` and even `explode` may not be that obvious for people of other programming languages.

Comment: @yergo I think most people (including me) are missing a nice mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve from OP where he shows the work/effort and attempts which he has done!

Comment: @Rizier123 [Not all questions benefit from including code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ;)

Comment: @yergo For sure, but I think in every question you should see that OP really tried something, did some work or did some research and he's **really** stuck and needs help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I first get the [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) of the `$url`, so that the last part is `users`, then I can grab that with taken the [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) from it)

```
$url = "http://example.com/accounts/users/list?showlist=true&id=4";
echo basename(dirname($url));
```

output:

```
users
```

Comment: That's even an easier solution than the one of me, even when I somehow expect that he cannot expect that the requested value will always be the second.

Comment: @D.Schalla Then OP has to specify his problem more and give an example of possible url's

Comment: Ever fought on using `dirname()` on url. Cool one!

Comment: Rizier: Absolutly correct, reason why I upvoted your solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that you always want to get the second value, you first use [parse_url](https://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) to get the path. Then you explode the path by "/" and filter the empty values. Your requested value will be in the second array value.

If you don't expect the value to be always in the second value, please specifiy your question further.

See:

```php
$url = 'http://example.com/accounts/users/list?showlist=true&id=4';

$parts = parse_url($url);
$fragments = explode('/', $parts['path']);
$fragments = array_filter($fragments);

$value = $fragments[2];

echo $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

- [Parsing URL with PHP](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [Explode](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) - one of the usefullnest methods ;)

And it goes this way:

```
$url = "http://example.com/accounts/users/list?showlist=true&id=4";

$parsed = parse_url($url); // parsing

$parsed['path'] = explode('/', $parsed['path']); // exploding path
print_r($parsed);
```

This bit of code will provide you with an array looking this way:

```
[scheme] => http
[host] => example.com
[path] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => accounts
        [2] => users
        [3] => list
    )

[query] => showlist=true&id=4
```

Rest is very similar to JS ;)

```
echo 'before last: ' . $parsed['path'][count($parsed['path'])-2];
```

will produce:

> before last: users